# Django site error with nginx- 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, nginx

I was trying to set up Django site as following:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:1234
...
August 10, 2016 - 12:10:50
Django version 1.9, using settings 'mysite_config_api.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:1234/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And when I try to access the site via  *mysite.com/admin* I got:

```
[10/Aug/2016 12:16:58] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x01\x01\x00\x01\x09\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x0cPATH_INFO/favicon.ico\x0e\x03REQUEST_METHODGET\x0c\x00QUERY_STRING\x0c\x00CONTENT_TYPE\x0e\x00CONTENT_LENGTH\x0b\x0cSERVER_ADDR172.30.1.244\x0b\x02SERVER_PORT80\x0b\x16SERVER_NAMEmysite.com\x0f\x08SERVER_PROTOCOLHTTP/1.1\t\x16HTTP_HOSTmysite.com\x0f')
[10/Aug/2016 12:16:58] "
                    PATH_INFO/favicon.icoREQUEST_METHODGET
                                                          QUERY_STRING
                                                                      CONTENT_TYPECONTENT_LENGTH

                                                                                                SERVER_ADDR172↓3????244
                                                                                                                       SERVER_PORT8?
                                                                                                                                    SERVER_NAMEde┴↓?e????±?↓c??┬d│↓cSERVER_PROTOCOLHTTP/1.1    HTTP_HOSTmysite.com" 400 -
```

my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mysite.com;

    location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/mysite/mysite_api/staticfiles;
    }

    location / {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:1234;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    }
}
```

What is going on? I tried to change the port (it was 8000 now 1234) and check that no other app is running on it. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with the following nginx config (taken from [that post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps)):

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mysite.com;

location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/path/to/staticfiles;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

runserver is not fcgi... there is not much of a point to use the development server behind nginx, but if you want to do so you have to use nginx `proxy_pass` instead of `fastcgi_pass`:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: ok, now it gave me: 2016/08/10 13:06:37 [error] 16795#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client...

Comment: are you sure that the ports do match? can you connect to http://127.0.0.1:1234 via browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following config. Servers may reserve port 80 (in my case this happened on a google VM). If it's not in use (you've checked) then you can simply replace 443 with 80.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name yourserver.com;

location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this one too and now it gave me: 2016/08/10 13:06:37 [error] 16795#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client...